# Disable all keyboard shortcuts in Electron.js

Tags: node.js, electron, keyboard-shortcuts

I am **trying to disable all keyboard shortcuts** in my electron.js app.

I tried the following ways (spoiler alert: they didn't work):

`globalShortcut.unregisterAll()`

and

```
globalShortcut.register('Alt+CommandOrControl+A', () => {
    console.log('not allowed')
  })
  globalShortcut.register('Alt+CommandOrControl+B', () => {
    console.log('not allowed')
  })
  globalShortcut.register('Alt+CommandOrControl+C', () => {
    console.log('not allowed')
  })
  globalShortcut.register('Alt+CommandOrControl+D', () => {
    console.log('not allowed') // and so on
  })
```

(i did this **^** for all the keys (from A to Z, 1 to 9, etc).
By the way, all of the code I tried I put into the `app.whenReady()` function.

Well, none of this worked. I saw a lot of articles with other *more abstract* ways, but they didn't work either.
I actually tried searching for an npm package too, but I didn't find any that would solve my problem.

I just need to completely disable all keyboard shortcuts from my electron app. Is there any other way (that actually works)?

Comment: not sure if best solution but what if you intercept [before-input-event](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-before-input-event) and preventDefault when the alt key is true

Comment: How would i do that? Can you write an answer with all the details?

Comment: @pushkin so can you please write an answer with more details?

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple solution ::

```
app.on('browser-window-focus', function () {
    globalShortcut.register("CommandOrControl+R", () => {
        console.log("CommandOrControl+R is pressed: Shortcut Disabled");
    });
    globalShortcut.register("F5", () => {
        console.log("F5 is pressed: Shortcut Disabled");
    });
});
```

```
app.on('browser-window-blur', function () {
    globalShortcut.unregister('CommandOrControl+R');
    globalShortcut.unregister('F5');
});
```

You can disable all the shortcuts by registering while the window is focused and unregister when blur.

See this question right here [Disable reload via keyboard shortcut electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39190476/disable-reload-via-keyboard-shortcut-electron-app)

EDIT :  disable all shortcuts  `globalShortcut.registerAll(accelerators, callback)`
accelerators String[] - an array of Accelerators.
callback Function
Registers a global shortcut of all accelerator items in accelerators. The callback is called when any of the registered shortcuts are pressed by the user.

`globalShortcut.unregisterAll()`
Unregisters all of the global shortcuts.

Comment: Thank you! This is working! But is there any way of doing this for all keys bulk? So I don't have to do it manually...

Comment: There is not a specific single  function or method to disable all the shortcuts. But you can use the registerAll and unregisterAll methods the same way as disabling single shortcut.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work... I guess ill just use your method for all shortcuts